# Is it possible to use vba to open text files that are fixed column delimited and different sizes

Tags: vba, excel

I have many text files which are first opened through vba and then processed. Nevertheless, all my text files are fixed length delimited. The only problem is that each file has a different column size.

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(51, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(71, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(86, 1), Array(96, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(114, 1), Array(123, 1), Array(132, 1), Array(141, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

and another one might be:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(77, 1), Array(141, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

But if I do it manually, Excel always suggests the correct array independently of the file.

Is it possible to either let Excel suggest these Arrays or at least get these Arrays some other way?

Comment: Is the `FieldInfo` valid throughout the entire file or can it happen that the first few "rows" of a file consist of 10 (delimited) columns and then your file changes to 11 or 8 columns?

Comment: Yes, in the same file the FieldInfo is the same. But each file has its own structure.

Comment: Well, then I don't quite understand. There are countless solutions on the web for importing text files into Excel using various different approaches (`Line Input` with `Split` or `select` with `ADO` or `.QueryTables.Add`). Afterwards, Excel usually formats the cells according to its content automatically. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you determine the structure of each file ?

Comment: With `Line Input` and `Split` the column count is determined by `Ubound(Split(strLineValue, ","))` and with `ADO` you don't need to specify with `select * from [$Sheet1]`. Once the data is in Excel it will get formatted automatically (according to the content in the cell).

Comment: @Ralph, to my understandig there are no delimiter, except the size of each field, hence my question how does Copito determine the structure of each file.

Comment: @h2so4 Oh, now I see. It seems that I missed all this time the `Fixed Width` as opposed to `Delimited`. But that just makes it a hole lot easier. Just copy the entire text file into column `A` using any of the above mentioned methods and then use `Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500").TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth`. Since you are not passing any `FieldInfo` Excel will decide for you and (I guess) that's what the OP wants because in the past Excel has decided correct.

Comment: @Ralph, turn that into a solution so we can upvote you. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the `Workbooks.OpenText` method to open the file, i.e. something like:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Temp\myFile.txt", _
                   Origin:=xlWindows, _
                   StartRow:=1, _
                   DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(51, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(71, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(86, 1), Array(96, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(114, 1), Array(123, 1), Array(132, 1), Array(141, 1)), _
                   TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

If so, you can just drop off the `FieldInfo` parameter and force Excel to make its own guess:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Temp\myFile.txt", _
                   Origin:=xlWindows, _
                   StartRow:=1, _
                   DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but Excel guesses different FieldInfos from the ones that it had guessed before. It caused two columns from joining up, whereas before they were separated. But it helped a bit!

Comment: Ahh, well if Excel's guesses aren't giving what you want, then you will have to do it the hard way and specify the specific widths you want.  There's really only those two alternatives - let it guess, or don't let it guess.